# Pass raw selection statement to laravel Eloquent while creating a Paginator instance

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination, laravel-query-builder

Pagination in Laravel is super easy. I simply go:

```
$posts = Post::where( .... );
$posts->paginate(20, ['ID', 'title', 'body'], ....);
```

I am trying to replace the ID,title,body array with: `ID, title, LEFT(body, 200)` But Laravel doesn't accept that! I found out that I should use this instead:

```
connection()->raw('ID, title, LEFT(body, 200) AS body');
```

For this to work, but the paginate method only accepts an array. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
$posts = Post::where( .... );
$posts->paginate(20, ['ID', 'title', \DB::raw('LEFT(body, 200) AS body')], ....);
```